# How to filter a query set

Tags: django

I'd like to filter the queryset obtained by filtering once, but I don't know how.

Currently, we are getting data from below.
And I want to get the data from the table separately on the condition
.
I just don't know how.

```py
#view
context_data = super(members,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
group = belong.objects.get(user=self.request.user).group
belong_queryset = belong.objects.filter(group=group)
#I want to apply belong_queryset to profile filter.
#profile_queryset = profile.objects.filter(belong_queryset)
```

Added model.

```py
#model
class profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=150, blank=True)



class belong(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user_profile')
    group = models.ForeignKey(group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    approval = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Sorry for the poor English and explanation.

Comment: Can you share your relevant models (`profile` and `belong`)?

Comment: Please tell me if you have other necessary parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two consecutive underscores (`__`) to look through a relation:

```
context_data = super(members,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
profile_queryset = profile.objects.filter(
    user__user_profile__group__belong__user=self.request.user
)
# ...
```

The filter name thus has the following parts:

```
       related belong   belongs of group
       _____^____           __^_
      /          \         /    \  
user__user_profile__group__belong__user
\_ /                \_ _/          \ _/
  v                   v             v
user of profile   group of belong  user of belong
```

You can make extra checks to check if the `belong`s are approved:

```
context_data = super(members,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
profile_queryset = profile.objects.filter(
    user__user_profile__group__belong__user=self.request.user,
    user__user_profile__approval=1,
    user__user_profile__group__belong__approval=1
)
# ...
```

Comment: It seems to work well.But because the level is high, I will investigate and decipher!
Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understood somehow!

Comment: Can you tell me what will happen if I want to apply approval = 1?

Comment: `approval` in the first belong, second belong, or both?

Comment: This is the first approval!
Thank you for adding.
That was a really big help!